# PowerShell v3 intellisense

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have latest PowerShell ISE v3 and everything. Just exploring it for the first time. And have found that the `Ctrl+Space` shortcut doesn't work at all, just never ever ever work. Even though in documentation and Microsoft Virtual Academy there is a reference to that intellisense shortcut. Some intellisense does work, there may be other shortcut keys not working. But it's one that I've just discovered anyway.

Am I missing something (Is it actually part of standard installation or there is an extension that I need to download)? It would just really be helpful if it worked.

The example I'm trying to run is from MVA, which is `Get-WmiObject win32_` and then trying to do the shortcut

I also noticed that when I keep the shortcut pressed - I can see a message "Intellisense..." flicking at the bottom of the screen.

```
Get-Host
```

returns:

```
Name             : Windows PowerShell ISE Host
Version          : 3.0
InstanceId       : fc07e6bc-9bdb-4515-a364-6de84298cd99
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : en-NZ
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Host.ISE.ISEOptions
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace

$PSVersionTable.PSVersion
```

returns:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
3      0      -1     -1
```

Some of the other shortcut keys do work, for example `Ctrl+J`works just fine.

Also if I run the `Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk`after typing it in - it executes successfully.

Also, if I backspace all the way to just `Get-Wmi` part it does open the suggestion for the rest of the command. Just not when I type in a class name to be passed in.

**For those having the same problem** as of this date and time the post has been written, the solution have NOT been found. Use `Get-CimInstance` command instead. It will give you the list of classes by `Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_` then press `Ctrl+Space`

Cheers.

Comment: Please execute : $PSVersionTable.PSVersion and let me know the output. Please also let me know the os version.

Comment: Please refer to my recent edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only experiencing this with using the Get-WmiObject cmdlet and Win32_* objects, then check out the link below. It's a quick read.

http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2013/11/26/getting-wmi-intellisense.aspx

One of the comments links to a tool from Microsoft that may add IntelliSense for WMI, but I haven't tested this.

Comment: I'll flag this as answer. However, it DID NOT solve the problem with intellisense missing even after installing the Wmi tool. Get-WmiObject is still missing intellisense! But I can use Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_ and the shortcut works.

Comment: Yeah, as I mentioned before, I hadn't tried that other WMI tool.

Eventually, Microsoft wants everyone to use CIM objects, since WMI objects use crusty old DCOM stuff, and CIM uses a newer open standard, when possible. If you want to read about why CIM over WMIC, here is an [interesting article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/08/24/introduction-to-cim-cmdlets.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Please download and install  following from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595:

1.If your OS is windows 7 x64 - select - Windows6.1-KB2506143-x64.msu file.
Else download as per your os version

After installation please restart your computer and run PowerShell again.
Ctrl + Space will work for intellisense.

Cheers!

Comment: This has already been installed ages ago and machine been restarted multiple times

Comment: Please refer to my recent edit, may be you could provide more help based on more information. Thanks.